# How to login as root user to Azure Kubernetes pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, root, azure-aks

I deployed Postgresql on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). It works fine.
But when I login to the pod with `kubectl exec -it pod_name bash`, it's automatically login with "**postgres**" user and I can't switch to the "**root**" user.

If I could able to login Kubernetes' nodes with ssh, I could use `docker exec -it -u root image_id` and login with "**root**" user, but as I know it's not possible on Azure.

How can I login to the pods as "root" user on AKS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add pod `securityContext`. where you can set the `UID 0` which is for root user. By default then, The Pod will run as root user. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo-pod
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
```

Or, If you want to run just the postgres container of your pod as root then you need to use container's security context.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo-2
spec:
  containers:
  - name: postgres
    image: postgres:13.2
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
      Privileged: true
```

Comment: But it's already deployed and on prod, I don't want to edit pod's YAML right now. Isn't it possible without editing the pod?

Comment: @yatta no, if  your default user is other then root then you don't have the permission to switch to root user.

Comment: it's not recommended to run containers this way, never run as root!

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it has helped me:

```
Kubectl -n [NAMESPACE](optional) exec --stdin --tty [POD_NAME] -- ./bin/bash
```